# Interaction between dictionary and lists

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Relatively new to Python here, I noticed a weird behaviour trying to use a list like "journal" for logging a dictionary update

The original code is really complex, so I broke it down to reproduce the bit that is not acting as I would expect

I have a list which will be converted to a dictionary

```
list2conv = ['Key1', 'Key2']
```

convert it to a dictionary

```
d_fromList = dict.fromkeys(list2conv)

for i in d_fromList:
    d_fromList[i] = [0, 0]
```

Creating the output list, which would be a kind of log of operations done in the dictionary, and adding some values

```
outList = []

for i in range(0, 3):
    d_fromList['Key1'][0] = d_fromList['Key1'][0] + 10
    d_fromList['Key2'][1] = d_fromList['Key2'][1] + 20
    outList.append(d_fromList['Key1'])
    outList.append(d_fromList['Key2'])
```

Actual result

```
[[30, 0], [0, 60], [30, 0], [0, 60], [30, 0], [0, 60]]
```

What I would expect

```
[[10, 0], [0, 20], [20, 0], [0, 40], [30, 0], [0, 60]]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: (base) C:\Users\max>conda --version
conda 4.6.8

(base) C:\Users\max>python --version
Python 3.7.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are experiencing is called aliasing.
It happens when you start to play around with nested lists/dict.
Here is a quick read:
http://www.cs.rpi.edu/~sibel/csci1100/fall2015/course_notes/exam2_review/aliasing.html

A quick fix is

```
for i in range(0, 3):
    d_fromList['Key1'][0] = d_fromList['Key1'][0] + 10
    d_fromList['Key2'][1] = d_fromList['Key2'][1] + 20
    outList.append(d_fromList['Key1'][:]) # copies the list
    outList.append(d_fromList['Key2'][:]) # copies the list
```

Comment: Thank you SO MUCH. I've gone crazy trying to debug something I thought was my mystake. Now it works, I'll go through the docs, too ;)

Answer (score 2):

There's a mistake in your code:

```
    d_fromList['Key2'][1] = d_fromList['Key1'][1] + 20
```

should be

```
    d_fromList['Key2'][1] = d_fromList['Key2'][1] + 20
```

Comment: Yes, you are right (edited)
The result is still wrong to me:
[[30, 0], [0, 60], [30, 0], [0, 60], [30, 0], [0, 60]]

Comment: @l3g10n3 Isn't that the result you're expecting?

Comment: sorry, I messed up the edits. Now it's correct, sorry :)

Comment: @l3g10n3 Alright, I think you should take the previous value from `outList` to increase them in your loop, instead of the `[0, 0]` from your `d_fromList`